# Runtime error while opening an oft template

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, oft

I have a mailing tool to create Outlook templates. The templates are stored as OLEObjects in one of the worksheets.

To use the templates I am creating a copy of them in the Temp folder. Afterwards the tool references it directly and opens with CreateItemFromTemplate. This works only on my PC. Others in my company get an error.

Code recreating the OLE object:

```
Sub RecreateObject(ObjectName As String, TemplateName As String) 'creates a     copy of the template stored in config in the users temp folder so that we can reference it from hard drive

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Variant
Dim objFolderItem As Variant
Dim oleObj As OLEObject

Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents" & Application.PathSeparator)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Set oleObj = wsConfig.OLEObjects(ObjectName)

'On Error GoTo Error1:

oleObj.Copy

If Dir(CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & TemplateName & ".oft"), vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
     objFolderItem.InvokeVerb ("Paste")
Else
    Kill Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & TemplateName & ".oft"
    oleObj.Copy
    objFolderItem.InvokeVerb ("Paste")
End If

EndThisSub:
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFolderItem = Nothing
Set oleObj = Nothing
Exit Sub

Error1:
MsgBox "Please re-open this file - template recreation failed."
GoTo EndThisSub:

End Sub
```

Code opening the template:

```
Sub OpenTemplate(TemplateName As String, InsHeight As Long, InsWidth As Long, InsTop As Long, InsLeft As Long)
    Dim response
    Dim varEditedTempBody As Variant, varEditedTempSubject As Variant
        'On Error GoTo Error1:
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        'On Error GoTo Error2:
        If objMail Is Nothing Then 'checks if any mails opened, if not fires procedure
                If curProcess = AddingTemplate Then
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                    Set objInspector = objMail.GetInspector
                        objMail.Display
                        objMail.Body = "" 'clearing the automatic signature
                End If
                If curProcess = EditingTemplate Then
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & frmTemplates.Controls(TemplateName).Value & ".oft")
                    'clearing the automatic signature by copying in the template after displaying
                    varEditedTempBody = objMail.HTMLBody
                    varEditedTempSubject = objMail.Subject
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"  & frmTemplates.Controls(TemplateName).Value & ".oft")
                        With objMail
                            .Display
                            .HTMLBody = varEditedTempBody
                            .Subject = varEditedTempSubject
                        End With
                    Set objInspector = objMail.GetInspector
                End If
                With objInspector
                    .WindowState = 2
                    .Height = InsHeight
                    .Width = InsWidth
                    .Top = InsTop
                    .Left = InsLeft
                End With
        Else
           response = MsgBox("A mail template is already opened. Would you like to proceed and close it without save?", vbYesNo)
                If response = vbYes Then 'if user agrees to closing  procedure fires
                    Call CloseTemplate
                    If curProcess = AddingTemplate Then
                        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                        Set objInspector = objMail.GetInspector
                            objMail.Display
                            objMail.Body = "" 'clearing the automatic signature
                    End If
                    If curProcess = EditingTemplate Then
                        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents" & Application.PathSeparator & frmTemplates.Controls(TemplateName).Value & ".oft")
                        varEditedTempBody = objMail.HTMLBody
                        varEditedTempSubject = objMail.Subject
                        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents" & Application.PathSeparator & frmTemplates.Controls(TemplateName).Value & ".oft")
                            With objMail
                                .Display
                                .HTMLBody = varEditedTempBody
                                .Subject = varEditedTempSubject
                            End With
                        Set objInspector = objMail.GetInspector
                    End If
                    With objInspector
                        .WindowState = 2
                        .Height = InsHeight
                        .Width = InsWidth
                        .Top = InsTop
                        .Left = InsLeft
                    End With
                Else
                    objMail.Display
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End If

 ExitThisSub:
        Exit Sub
Error1:
        MsgBox "Cannot open the Outlook application. Please note that mailer uses Outlook by default and without it it's not possible to use the program."
        GoTo ExitThisSub:

Error2:
        MsgBox "The template cannot be opened from hard drive. Please contact ...."
        GoTo ExitThisSub:
End Sub
```

I get the error on this line:

```
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & frmTemplates.Controls(TemplateName).Value & ".oft")
```

saying: run-time error '-2147286960(80030050)' Cannot open the file /path/ . the file may not exist, you may not have the permission to open it...

I read about this and the suggestion was that an instance of objOutlook may somehow lock the file. So I've set it to nothing everywhere after playing with templates or recreating them but it still returned this error.

Comment: What happens if you give direct path `eg C:\Users\Om3r\Documents\` ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer - basically it's the same error - also, if I try to open the .oft file from windows I get a similar error saying that the file may not exist, you may not have the permission to open it. It seems to be the case of accessing the file at all.

Comment: `frmTemplates` is not declared anywhere?

Comment: Also, when you add the `.oft` as an OLE object to the workbook, remember the name of the `.oft` file. Then when you `oleObj.Copy` & `objFolderItem.InvokeVerb ("Paste")` , it get its original name (the name it had when imported).

Answer (score 0):

Your file or directory is ReadOnly. Change the properties of the directory and that's all.